# sql*loader loading csv file with 3.5 million records

Tags: oracle, bulkinsert, sql-loader, oracle12c

How can i load csv file with 3.5 million records into database table?

my csv file format:

```
code,doi,type,j_code,title,is_no,ib_no
"ETO072","10.10ISSN","J_ID","BEJ","ABCDEF","19-38","07-93"
"ETO073","10.11ISSN","J_ID","BEJ","NSKDJJ","19-39","07-94"
"ETO074","10.12ISSN","J_ID","BEJ","WEWDSD","19-40","07-95"
"ETO075","10.13ISSN","J_ID","BEJ","UOISDJ","19-41","07-96"
```

table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE CNTNT 
   (    ID NUMBER, 
    code NUMBER, 
    TYPE VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    is_no VARCHAR2(13 BYTE), 
    ib_no VARCHAR2(13 BYTE), 
    J_code VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    TITLE VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    JCODE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    DOI VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
     PRIMARY KEY (ID), 
   );
```

control file:

```
load data 
infile 'test.csv' "str '\n'"
append
into table CNTNT 
fields terminated by ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
trailing nullcols
           ( 
            code,
            DOI ,
            TYPE,
            J_CODE ,
            TITLE ,
            is_no,
            ib_no,
            ID "id_seq.nextval"
           )
```

this is what i am using to run loader:

```
sqlldr CONTROL=test.ctl
       LOG=test.log
       BAD=test.bad
       skip=1;
```

What are the changes i need to do in control file or sqlldr command to achieve this?

Comment: in your table duplicate columns are there please check and What you have tried till now?

Comment: @Tarun i have updated the column name. when i ran the sql loader it is not taking more the 1MB file

Comment: Do you have a question? Is there an error whilst loading? What is it? Is it a command line error or is there a problem with SQL*Loader? What is the problem? Have you looked in your log file? What does the log file say? The size of the table doesn't make much difference.